# How to reset google sheets so data collected by forms are put into first free cell

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-forms

Hey guys this may be a silly question but i have been Googling everywhere on how to reset a spreadsheet. I am currently having this issue where every time i erase data from the spreadsheet and then have a user to input some data via the Form the information gets placed where where the last cell once had information.

eg: http://gyazo.com/72b5e58fc17dae3c76cebcd0d72e30e0

and then when i delete this data and have the user input some information again, it will start the posted data on Row 8 and so forth.

Is there a way to reset this so that data will be stored on Row 1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you try deleting those rows instead of erasing their content ?

Comment: thank you i knew it would be a silly thing, i did  not spot that at all thank yuo so much for your help i have marked this as the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: It's not working anymore. You have to click on the trash bin icon on each response in response summary (only form creator will see it)

Comment: Never knew that clearing and deleting rows are two different things!

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete all the responses in the form, then go back to the responses sheet and delete (not clear) all the rows (not cells) of data.

It's possible to make a Google App Script to do the last part for you.

You can create a *Named Version* (in File > Version History) before you delete the responses, if you want to keep a record of them.